# get self and class object inside method in python class

Tags: python

What is the best way to get object of the class and self simultaniously inside a class method in python?

example:

```
class A:

        def __pos__(self):
            cls = type(self)
            return cls(self)
```

i need both cls and self to create new instance of the current class. If i use @classmethod i would lost access to self. Dont want to hardcode

```
 cls = type(self)
```

either in each and every method. Guess it might be better way to get self and cls objects ib the same method...

thx

Comment: Why not just use return ```A()```?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You want the instance of the class to return *itself*? What is the expected result here?

Comment: @Joshua Nixon  Becouse i want to support inheritance in case class B would inherit class A, then it would produce B(self) this way

Comment: @r.ook. It should retur new class instance of the class A or any class down the inheritance tree in case of inheritance involved. I teken this code as an example.Question is really is : how to get both self and class object inside the same class method in general ( without hardcoding cls = type(current_class) each time?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to hardcode ``cls = type(self)``"? If you want to get the class, you have to ask for it. What is your criteria for not wanting to do that? Using decorators such as ``classmethod`` isn't any shorter either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible to access to class object inside the method via

```
self.__class__
```

In this case i can get both class object and self simultaneously inside the same method.

Comment: This offers no benefit over `type(self)`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica  Kind of but at least it shorter....Other way is to add type(self) to __init__ (which would be mutable from instance) or make property of it. Anyway nobody gave universal answer on the my question so i did as i described above.

Comment: It's not shorter at all. `type(self)` is 10 characters. `self.__class__` is 14.

Comment: Are you under the impression that you have to save the result of `type(self)` to a variable before using it? You don't. `return type(self)(self)` works fine.